# Share Checkpoint VPN with OS X Internet Sharing

Tags: macos, network, wifi, vpn, internet-sharing

I want to share my VPN connection over wifi using Internet Sharing, but something doesn't work.

My current setup is:

- Macbook Pro: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
- VPN client: CheckPoint Endpoint Security for Mac

[image]

I've tried the steps described [here](https://blog.netnerds.net/2016/11/share-vpn-with-os-x-sierra-internet-sharing/) but something doesn't work.

Some of the NAT rules that I've tried:

```bsh
nat on utun1 from bridge100:network to any -> (utun1)

#OR 
nat on utun1 from 192.168.2.2/24 to any -> (utun1)

#OR 
nat on en6 from 192.168.2.2/24 to any -> (en6)
nat on utun1 from 192.168.2.2/24 to any -> (utun1)

#and many more...
```

My script looks like this:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.forwarding=1
sysctl -w net.inet.ip.fw.enable=1
sysctl -w net.inet6.ip6.forwarding=1

#disables pfctl
pfctl -d
sleep 1

#flushes all pfctl rules
pfctl -F all
sleep 1

#starts pfctl and loads the rules from the nat-rules file
pfctl -f ./nat-rules -e
```

The Internet Sharing works without VPN enabled, but after I enable it, I get **Connected, no internet...**.

Is something wrong with my NAT rule or is the VPN, being through CheckPoint Endpoint Security?

Comment: There appears to be something broken with DNS. I have a similar experience, except that I can connect, I just cannot look up sites. If I manually change the DNS server in the device sharing the connection (iPhone), I can reach sites. However, I cannot get the iPhone to use the DNS server that the Mac uses after starting CheckPoint VPN. https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/125372/internet-sharing-handing-out-wrong-dns-server-address has some info about DNS issues, but seems to merely explain what you and I are seeing, i.e. VPN is breaking the Mac DNS lookup.

Comment: In other words, I cannot reach sites via the VPN, which is the whole point of using Internet Sharing with the VPN.